# Knockoutjs : How to add title to options in select

Tags: drop-down-menu, attributes, knockout.js

I use Knockoutjs options binding to populate my selects as this

```
<select data-bind="value: val, options: options, optionsText: 'text', optionsValue: 'ID'">
</select>
```

But for some option, the text is the same. Then I would like to add a title attribute to add information. Can I do that with knockout without modifying knockoutjs itself ?

May be using a function in optionsText, but I can't see How

Comment: What do you mean "add a title" attribute? What would that look like?

Comment: something like <option title="title" value="value">text</option>

Answer (score 6):

You can do it using the *foreach* binding, like this:

```
<select data-bind="foreach: options, value: selectedValue">
    <option data-bind="value: ID, text: text, attr: {title: title}" ></option>
</select>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AGcd4/) is a working example.