# Knockout select binding - Add Title

Tags: select, knockout.js, binding

I'm using the following code to set up a select list - i need to add a title to each item. Is this possible?

```
<select tabindex="-1" name="myDropDown" data-bind="
                visible: isVisible,
                options: $parent.myList,
                optionsText: 'name',
                optionsCaption: '- Select an item-',
                value: selectedItem,
                resizeOuter: true"></select>
```

Comment: What do you mean on title? Do you want have a tooltip for each item or something else?

Comment: This is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733430/knockoutjs-how-to-add-title-to-options-in-select

Comment: yes a tooltip. @DevPat - is there any way to do this without using a foreach? My other bindings dont work with foreach e.g visible is ignored. And i need a caption as well

Comment: @newbie_86 please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927954/add-extra-attribute-to-option-through-knockout/23928303#23928303 which uses the `optionsAfterRender` to add additional attributes.

Comment: @newbie_86: here is the working example http://plnkr.co/edit/gDbqJC7X8QE35qMSJh7v?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `foreach` binding, something like:

```
<select  tabindex="-1" name="myDropDown" data-bind="foreach: $parent.myList, value: selectedItem, visible: isVisible, resizeOuter: true">
    <option data-bind="value: myListValue, text: myListText, attr: {title: myListTitle}" ></option>
</select>

self.myList= ko.observableArray([
                                 {myListText: "first", myListValue: 1, myListTitle: "the first"}, 
                                 {myListText: "second", myListValue: 2, myListTitle: "the second"},   
             ]);
```